# JavaScript: Transform array of objects to an object

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I am making an app that uses `sequelize` and the `JSON` value returned is:

```
[
  { key: 'PREFIX', value: 'm.' },
  { key: 'OWNER_ID', value: '14901414891498' },
  { key: 'GUILD_ID', value: '525219058950109' }
]
```

But I want to know if is possible to reorganize this json object to something like this:

```
{ prefix: 'm.', owner_id: '330406276972412928', guild_id: '525219058950109'}
```

I searched some methods of `JSON` object manipulation with Javascript but none of them fit in my need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
const data = [ { key: 'PREFIX', value: 'm.' }, { key: 'OWNER_ID', value: '14901414891498' }, { key: 'GUILD_ID', value: '525219058950109' } ];

const obj = data.reduce((acc, {key, value}) => ({
  ...acc, [key.toLowerCase()]: value
}), {});

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.fromEntries` and transform the objects into `[key, value]` tuples.

```js
const data = [
  { key: 'PREFIX', value: 'm.' },
  { key: 'OWNER_ID', value: '14901414891498' },
  { key: 'GUILD_ID', value: '525219058950109' }
]

const newData = Object.fromEntries(data.map(({ key, value }) => 
  [key.toLowerCase(), value]))

console.log(newData)
```

Comment: Thank you!! It worked